# Why doesn't pattern matching on a property of a record compile?

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

**Why doesn't pattern matching on a property of a record compile?**

```
type Cell = { X:int; Y:int }

let isNeighbor cell1 cell2 =
    match cell1.X, cell2.X with
    | cell1, cell2 when cell1.X <> cell2.X 
                    ||  cell1.Y <> cell2.Y -> let xAligned = IsValueNeighbor cell1.X cell2.X
                                              let yAligned = IsValueNeighbor cell1.Y cell2.Y

                                              xAligned && yAligned
    | _ -> false
```

**Error:**

> The type 'int' is not compatible with the type 'Cell'

The following expression appears to have an issue:

```
    cell1.X <> cell2.X 
||  cell1.Y <> cell2.Y
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do

```
match cell1.X, cell2.X with
| cell1, cell2
```

you have created a new `cell1` variable, which is `cell1.X` (an int).

I would probably have just used an if here, or change to `| _,_ when ...`

Answer (score 4):

As John Palmer already explained, you are shadowing the original parameters. If pattern matching does not feel well suited `if-elif-else` might be better. If you want to use pattern matching, the following could be helpful:

```
let isNeighbor { X=x1; Y=y1 } { X=x2; Y=y2} =
    match abs(x1-x2), abs(y1-y2) with
    | 0,1 | 1,0 | 1,1 -> true
    | _ -> false
```

Remove the `1,1` pattern if diagonal adjacent cells should not be neighbors. And then, there is also Euclidean distance...